# Merge two array in one array (element need to merge too)

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I want to merge array like in:

[image]

What is the shortest/cleanest way to do that ? Is there a way with reduce or map ?

PS: Green array will always have the same size

Input

```
[
  [
    ["X"],
    ["A"],
    ["B"],
    ["C"],
    ["D"]
  ],
  [
    ["Y", "Z"],
    [1, "M"],
    [2, "a"],
    [3, "p"],
    [4, "?"]
  ]
]
```

Output that i want

```
[
  ["X", "Y", "Z"],
  ["A", 1, "M"],
  ["B", 2, "a"],
  ["C", 3, "p"],
  ["D", 4, "?"]
]
```

Comment: Please see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and, if applicable, [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - Please post your code here directly, preferably in a working snippet, demonstrating the issue.

Comment: At least explain what the colors mean.

Comment: Color just represent an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just map over one of the arrays and `concat` it with the other array.

```js
var array1 = [
  ["1"],
  ["2"],
  ["3"]
];
var array2 = [
  ["A", "B"],
  ["R", "S"],
  ["x", "y"]
];

function mergeArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr2.map((item, index) => {
    return arr1[index].concat(item);
  });
}

console.log(mergeArrays(array1, array2));
```

Comment: I just replace your merge array by a reduce to be able to have as many green array as I want but yes this solve my problem thank you :)